# Java: client, client, (threaded) server, streams client info, JPanel created but messages(?) block start of game

Tags: java, multithreading, stream, jpanel

I am developing a small scale `client1/ client2, server (threaded) TCP game`. In trying to deal with latency issues I've realised there were flaws in my `transmitState()`. It was forcing unnecessary info down the comms streams creating sluggishness, leaving cars in different places in the JPanel, and was basically just wrong. So I took it out.

But in doing so I've created problems in that despite all comms, protocols, threads, 'messenger's and everything working, somewhere in my logic I've halted the start of the game by not allowing for the `repaint()`, `transmitState()` and `receiveState()` to do their job in logical orders.

I really can't see where I've gone wrong. Any suggestions?

NOTE: `if` conditions in `keyPressed` case statement tests to get sprite to 'spin' 360degrees on left right etc. and vel is velocity so can't exceed 100. `carRem` = car remote client. I know there's a lot of code but I've been (rightly) told off in the past for not including enough code so I think all of this shows what is needed to be shown (let me know if I'm wrong :) ).

**TRANSMIT STATE:**

```
public void transmitState(String s)
    {
        try
        {
            outputStream.writeBytes(s + "\n");
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
```

**RECEIVE STATE:**

```
    public void receiveState()
    {
        try
        {
            messageIn = inputStream.readLine();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
        testState(messageIn);
    }
```

**TEST STATE:**

```
public void testState(String s)
{
if (s.equals("l") || s.equals("r") || s.equals("u") || s.equals("d"))
{
  c = s.charAt(0);
  this.i2 = i2;
  this.vel2 = vel2;
  this.carRem = carRem;

  switch (c)
  {
    case 'l':
      if (i2 == 0)
      {
        i2 = 15;
      }
      else
      {
        i2--;
      }
      carRem.setCurrentImage(i2);
      break;
    case 'r':
      if (i2 == 15)
      {
        i2 = 0;
      }
      else
      {
        i2++;
      }
      carRem.setCurrentImage(i2);
      break;
    case 'u':
      if (vel2 == 100)
      {

      }
      else
      {
        vel2 = vel2 + 10;
        carRem.setVel(vel2);
      }
      break;
    case 'd':
      if (vel2 == 0)
      {

      }
      else
      {
        vel2 = vel2 - 10;
        carRem.setVel(vel2);
      }
      break;
  }
}
}
```

JPANEL (with most client functionality):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class UIPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener
{       
    //sprite creation stuff, works fine (excluded here)
    private Timer timer;
    private CarLocal carLoc;
    private CarRemote carRem;
    private String carLocColour;

    private ClientMessenger cliMess = null;

    public UIPanel(CarLocal carLoc, CarRemote carRem, ClientMessenger cliMess)
    {
        this.carLoc = carLoc;
        this.carRem = carRem;
        this.cliMess = cliMess;

        images1 = new ImageIcon[TOTAL_IMAGES];
        images2 = new ImageIcon[TOTAL_IMAGES];

        carLocColour = carLoc.getColour();
            //setting sprites and testing order  (works fine and excluded here)

        this.addKeyListener(this);
        this.setFocusable(true);

       timer = new Timer(80, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
    {

    }

   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        int i1 = carLoc.getCurrentImage();
        int i2 = carRem.getCurrentImage();
        int vel1 = carLoc.getVel();
        int vel2 = carRem.getVel();
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) 
        {
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                if(i1 == 0)
                {
                    i1 = 15;
                }
                else
                {
                    i1--;
                }
                carLoc.setCurrentImage(i1);
                cliMess.transmitState("l");
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                if(i1 == 15)
                {
                    i1 = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    i1++;
                }
                carLoc.setCurrentImage(i1);
                cliMess.transmitState("r");
                break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                if(vel1 == 100)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    vel1 = vel1 + 10;
                    carLoc.setVel(vel1);
                    cliMess.transmitState("u");
                }
                break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                if(vel1 == 0)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    vel1 = vel1 - 10;
                    carLoc.setVel(vel1);
                    cliMess.transmitState("d");
                }
                break;
        }

        carLoc.setCurrentImage(i1);
        carLoc.setVel(vel1);;
   }

   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
    {

   }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        repaint();
        cliMess.receiveState();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        for(int iVel1 = carLoc.getVel(); iVel1 > 0; iVel1 = iVel1 - 10)
        {
            carLoc.forwardCalc(); 
        }
        for(int iVel2 = carRem.getVel(); iVel2 > 0; iVel2 = iVel2 - 10)
        {
            carRem.forwardCalc();
        }

        super.paintComponent(g);
        int i1X = carLoc.getCarX();
        int i1Y = carLoc.getCarY();
        int i2X = carRem.getCarX();
        int i2Y = carRem.getCarY();
        int currentImage1 = carLoc.getCurrentImage();
        int currentImage2 = carRem.getCurrentImage();
        Color c0 = Color.black;
        //includes some graphics stuff, works fine, excluded here

        images1[currentImage1].paintIcon( this, g, i1X, i1Y);
        images2[currentImage2].paintIcon( this, g, i2X, i2Y);
    }
}
```

Comment: I should point out that as soon as the server is cancelled (CTRL + C in cmd prompt) the cars start moving *locally* as they should have.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the amount of data you plan to send, you may need to call [flush()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush%28%29) to ensure that the data is sent without requiring the internal buffer to be full.

Comment: OK, thanks, i'll try that out. Would you recommend if this were to be from clients sending data for the server to thread and bounce back, or flushed by the threaded server bouncing the data back? Or does that make no difference? It's sending a continual stream of Strings btw.

Comment: Well, so far that's not really made much of a difference, but I appreciate the suggestion :)

Comment: You should flush after each message you want received immediately, irregardles of the direction and originator.

Comment: OK, well that might well have helped, but it hasn't helped the part of the question I'm still stuck on. Thanks though.